# Silverlight autocompletebox validate item selected

Tags: silverlight, validation

I just need to validate that at least one item in an autocompletebox has been selected (meaning the textbox is not blank) when a button is clicked.

My list etc is working fine ... Im just not sure how to do validation. In fact this is the first of any such silverlight validation I've done as the bulk of our work is readonly dashboard type screens.

Comment: Please, provide xaml to make it easier to define problem.